# How to compile backend without android app in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio

So I have an android app with an app engine backend (App-Engine Connected Android Project). Back when I used to work in Eclipse, I could compile the backend, then generate the endpoints for android, and then work on android. But now on Android Studio I don’t seem to be able to build the server without it building the android app as well. The problem with that is my android app is not ready to compile. So how do I work on the server and compile it and deployment apart from the android app? Needless to say I am extremely new to Android Studio. But I know the eclipse workflow, which is

1. Work on server code (develop, compile, test)
2. Generate client endpoints for android

Answer (score 0):

Your Android Studio Project is likely to be a multi-module project i.e. it will be having a server side app and an Android app.

Android Studio uses Gradle as its build tool and hence you have the option on working on specific Gradle tasks (clean, compile, build, etc) on each of the projects separately. You need not always launch or run the overall Build process that will try to look at dependencies and then build all the stuff.

Since you want to work on the Server app separately and make that ready, I suggest that you can run the build tasks specific to that project. In the commander view you will see Gradle tasks for each project separately and you can run that. Alternately, you can also go to the terminal and look at the tasks and/or run those separately.

For e.g. let's say that you have an Android Studio project named `MyApp` and it has two modules in it called `app` and `api`. The `app` is the Android module and `api` is the Server side module with Cloud Endpoints. If you visit the terminal or command line and go to the root folder you can run Gradle specific tasks for each of the modules via `gradle <modulename>:<taskname>`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a project structure of **MyApplication** (root) with **app** (android) and **backend** (appengine)

If you want to build only the **backend**.  You should run the `assemble` task on that gradle module. Unfortunately running the task directly from the "Gradle" tab doesn't seem to run the task against the module alone, it runs it on everything. So you have two options.

1. run build from the command line : `./gradlew :backend:assemble`
2. create a run configuration in the IDE for your gradle build, with the values 

   Name:`Backend Build` (or something),

   Gradle project: `MyApplication:backend` (pick from dropdown),

   Tasks `:backend:assemble`

   and use that to build your backend by itself.

Both seem kind of annoying. You can also try to initiate an individual module rebuild directly when you run.

If you take a look at your **backend** run configuration (Run -> Edit Configurations), in the section `Before launch:`, you see a `Make` which does a project rebuild.  You might need to remove that from the run configuration so it doesn't try to rebuild the whole project before deploying. To replace that with a gradle assemble of your module, click the +, and add a new `Run Gradle task` and configure it as above in "2".

I've filed a bug against this : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=168875&thanks=168875&ts=1429554595 I think the default behavior should be switched (use gradle assemble instead of make).

Generating Client libraries is done with some magic in Gradle. If you look at the build file for your Android App, it should reference a configuration on your **backend** called `android-endpoints` so the endpoint are generated as a compile dependency of your **app** module